# Cross compiler Makefile *.o no such file or directory errors

Tags: c, makefile, cross-compiling

This is my Makefile

```
CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -I.
OBJS=main.o progA.o progB.o progC.o
TARGET=main

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
            $(CC) -static -o $@ $(OBJS)
            rm -f *.o

progA.o: progA.h progA.c
progB.o: progA.h progB.h progB.c
progC.o: progA.h progC.h progC.c
main.o: progA.h main.h main.c

all: $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(TARGET)
```

and I get errors

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static -o main main.o progA.o progB.o progC.o
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: progA.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: progB.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: progC.o: No such file or directory
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Is this because I'm using cross compiler?
I don't know what's the problem.
How can I fix it?

Comment: First of all, remove the `rm` command from the recipe for `main`.  It is non-idiomatic for a recipe to remove the prerequisites of its rule.  Among other things, doing so interferes with `make`s ability to avoid unnecessary recompilation.  You already have `make clean` to clean those up when you want to do.

Comment: For `make` to get to the point of building `main`, it must either observe all the prerequisite `.o` files to initially exist, or it must think it has successfully created the missing ones.  The preceding `make` output will indicate which it thinks it has built.  If indeed the `.o` files do not exist in the working directory at that point (check this!) then either there's something you're not telling us, or the implicit rules selected for building the `.o` files are completing without error, yet not creating the expected outputs.

Comment: regardinng: `CFLAGS=-Wall -I.`  You should enable the warnings when compiling.  Suggest: `CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -I.` then fix those warnings.

Comment: regarding; `all: $(TARGET)`  this rule should be before any of the other rules

Comment: regarding: `progA.o: progA.h progA.c` and similar statements: `make` will try to convert the *.h file to the *.o file.  I.E. the `*.c` file should be listed first in the list of dependences

Comment: regarding these kinds of statements: `CFLAGS=-Wall -I.`  the `=` will result in the macro being re-evaluated every time it is referenced.  Strongly suggest using: `:=`  as in: `CFLAGS := -Wall -I.`  so each macro is only evaluated once